# Kinetic energy of electrons being quenched

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I hear about the quenching of kinetic energy of electrons in two different contexts (flat bands (Energy vs k) and Landau levels caused by applying a strong magnetic field perpendicular to the 2DEG).

In both cases, looking at the electronic band structure (E vs k), it seems that they both boil down to the energy of the electrons not having any momentum (k) dependence.

But, it appears to me that, if the system has multiple flat bands or if the electrons reside in not just the lowest LL, but across multiple LLs, they are allowed to have different kinetic energies.

So, my question is the following:

When they say the kinetic energy of electrons is quenched, it does not necessarily mean that the actual value is zero but all those electrons are forced to have the same kinetic energy. If this is a true statement, how should I understand that electrons residing on different flat bands or Landau Levels end up having the same kinetic energy? (or do they not?)

Comment: Could you explain the statement "...it appears to me that, if the system has multiple flat bands or if the electrons reside in not just the lowest LL, but across multiple LLs, they are allowed to have different kinetic energies"? I don't understand why multiple flat-bands would lead to this condition.

Comment: @Niall I made that statement because when B field is applied, Landau quantization leads to electrons taking on discrete kinetic energies in the form of $E_n = \hbar \omega_c (n+1/2)$

Comment: A precise reference would be helpful. Who  is "they"? Are you referring to fluorescence. quenching?

Comment: @AndreaAlciato the fact the kinetic energy of the electrons in the flat bands is quenched and the fact that turning on a strong magnetic field and apply it perpendicular to 2DEG results in massively degenerate Landau levels with electrons' kinetic energy gets quenched. I'd like to know what is meant by 'quenched.' It does not seem like it necessarily means the kinetic energy goes to zero.

Comment: @Blackwidow Still not sure we're on the same page. Anyway, flat band means d2E/dk2=0. Now 1/m*=d2E/dk2=0, m* being the reduced mass, which becomes infinite. So electrons are stuck, "quenched".

Comment: @AndreaAlciato i guess applying a perpendicular B field and achieving Landau levels change a parabolic band structure (or any band structure for that matter) to flat bands. So, that's how the kinetic energy of electrons is quenched? Landau level quantization is a way to turn curved band structure into flat bands?

Comment: @Blackwidow. Have a look at this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shubnikov%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect . "In the presence of a magnetic flux density B, the energy eigenvalues of this system are described by Landau levels. As shown in Fig 1, these levels are equidistant along the vertical axis. Each energy level is substantially flat inside a sample (see Fig 1). " Is this what you mean?

Comment: @AndreaAlciato Yes, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard the word "quenching" in this context, but it seems you are mixing up some concepts. The energy of the Landau levels  $E_n = \hbar \omega_c (n+1/2)$ do not represent kinetic energy, but are instead the eigenvalues you get by applying the Hamiltonian $H$ which must include at least kinetic energy *and* the magnetic field.

I am not sure what you would get by only applying the kinetic energy operator, but you can see from the flat dispersion that the group velocities are zero, $v_g = dE/dk = 0$, which in a Newtonian sense could be understood as zero kinetic energy. I would guess this is what is meant by quenching, the flat band means zero group velocity which again means that the electrons are not moving anywhere (in the particle picture).

Hopefully that helps!